# SQL Server : query code

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a T-SQL query for SQL Server to pull some information from all the databases. I will then run this nightly and email the report to who it needs to go to.

I have two separate scripts which I want to merge so all the data is formatted nicely in a table.

```
SELECT
    db.name AS DBName,
    type_desc AS Filetype,
    Physical_Name AS Location,
    (size * 8) / 1024 AS SizeMB,
    DATABASEPROPERTYEX(db.name, 'Status') AS Recovery
FROM
    sys.master_files mf
INNER JOIN
    sys.databases db ON db.database_id = mf.database_id
```

This returns Name, Type, Location, Size and Status. I would like to merge it with this script:

```
SELECT 
    Database_Name,
    CONVERT( SmallDateTime , MAX(Backup_Finish_Date)) as Last_Backup, 
    DATEDIFF(d, MAX(Backup_Finish_Date), Getdate()) as Days_Since_Last
FROM 
    MSDB.dbo.BackupSet
WHERE 
    Type = 'd'
GROUP BY 
    Database_Name
```

This produces a table with Name, Last backup and days since last backup.

The end result is one query I can run to produce a table with:

```
Name, Type, Location, Size, Status, Last backup & Days since last backup.
```

I will then try to work out a way to run this, export it as HTML and email it to myself every morning so I have a quick overview of my environment.

Thanks, 
Rob

Comment: Have you tried to combine them at all? Looked at what columns between the three tables you may be able to join on?

Comment: I have tried to combine them every which way I could think but keep getting errors.

Comment: Can you post some of your attempts and the errors you're receiving?

Comment: I have deleted all my failed attempts but what I think is happening is I am selecting the first lot of data from the table 'sys.master_files mf' and the second lot from 'MSDB.dbo.Backupset'. So I think I need some way to query both tables for the data and them merge or combine the results into a table. Some how..

Comment: Yep, see in the first query you're joining two tables together. You need to find a common column to join that third table in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like the following will work.  You already have the database name (`sys.databases.name`) in your first query, so you can use this to join to `MSDB.dbo.BackupSet`.  Beyond that, you are using an aggregate function in your second query.  So you simply need to group by the columns you are selecting from the first query.

```
SELECT
db.name AS DBName,
mf.type_desc AS Filetype,
mf.Physical_Name AS Location,
(mf.size*8)/1024 AS SizeMB,
DATABASEPROPERTYEX(db.name, 'Status') AS Recovery,
CONVERT( SmallDateTime , MAX(back.Backup_Finish_Date)) as Last_Backup, 
DATEDIFF(d, MAX(back.Backup_Finish_Date), Getdate()) as Days_Since_Last
FROM sys.master_files mf
INNER JOIN sys.databases db
    ON db.database_id = mf.database_id
INNER JOIN MSDB.dbo.BackupSet back
    ON back.Database_Name = db.name
GROUP BY db.name, mf.type_desc, mf.Physical_Name, mf.size
```

In the future, please post the queries that you have tried so far so that we can help point out where they may have gone wrong.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks for that. It was something I was working on a few weeks ago and I lost all my attempts so I had to admit defeat and ask for help. Cheers.